# My friend's Windows 8 laptop not connecting to their Wi-Fi router in their house but can connect to other routers

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I’m trying to sort out a problem with my friends’ laptop. They are on Windows 8.1 and they said they did something to it—I think it was something like they were trying to log out of one of the people in their house Skype user and log in to their user and they then deleted the Wi-Fi profile and then it stopped working—I don’t really understand exactly what they did.

But the laptop connects to other routers like my one and another BT router. Other Wi-Fi compatible devices in their house work on that router like their iPhones and iPads. I’ve researched online a lot about it and done quite a lot of different things to see if I can fix it for example doing complete a reset on the router, updating the driver through windows - the driver was up to date anyway.

When I try to connect to the router, it seems quite normal trying to connect to it and then it says something like “this is taking longer than usual,” then it says it can’t connect to the network—try to resolve the problem or something—and I’ve done that where it does tests to try to find out the problem and fix it but they haven't worked.

Also after it fails to connect to the router, the router stops showing up in the Wi-Fi options and you have to go to “Manage known networks” and click forget on the network, and then reboot the router for the laptop to see it again.

- **Laptop:** Lenovo B590
- **Their router:** BT Home Hub 4

Comment: You may need to "Now press the WPS button on the top of your Hub. The Wireless light on the Hub will flash orange ". See [How do I create a wireless connection to my Hub 3, Hub 4 or Hub 5 using WPS?](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44213/~/how-do-i-create-a-wireless-connection-to-my-hub-3,-hub-4-or-hub-5-using-wps%3F)

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but it didn't work, I might try again tomorrow if Kimmax's solution doesn't work tomorrow. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to reboot the router before doing the steps below, it may have problems with connecting "new" devices.

---

Try to uninstall the wireless card from the device manager (Do **NOT** delete the driver, **DO NOT** check the box which asks to delete the driver or you will end up with a non working card, untill you reinstall the driver). This will remove all saved networks, network settings and will do a complete reset on this network interface. After rebooting try again to connect to the network.
When this does not help they may have changed something on the routers side, or it's most likely not a problem with the network card.

[image]
*Note: The network card is not required to have wireless is name but this is a good first sign that you found the right controller*

Comment: Awesome thanks man sounds a great idea. I will try that when I go to my friends' house tomorrow!

Comment: Also, if you go to *Manage Wireless Networks* under the *Network and Sharing Center*, does his home wifi still appear in the list of remembered networks? If it does, you can try and choose to forget the network and try reconnecting again.